# How to "import" a namespace in a TypeScript Definition file

Tags: typescript

The `moment.js` type definition is declared within a `namespace`:

```
declare namespace moment {
  interface Moment {
...
```

In order to declare an object of type `Moment`, I do:

```
let myMoment: moment.Moment;
```

My question is - is there a way to "import" the `moment` namespace so I can avoid repeating every time? Very much like C#.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's a way to "import" an entire namespace, but you can do it on an item-by-item basis like this:

```
type Moment = moment.Moment
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES6 style imports then you can simply do something like following.

```
import { Moment, Duration, OrAnyOtherExportedMemberFromMoment } from "moment";
let myMoment: Moment;
let myDuration: Duration;
```

*In case you need this in your type definition files from you source file:*

With `compilerOptions.declaration` set to `true` in your `tsconfig.json`, and using [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) (search for `tsResult.dts.pipe`), you can generate type definitions from your source files.

Hope this helps.